# MySql: Query Optimization (multiple left joins)

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, left-join

The following query takes more than an hour to execute when the **where clause** contains ~50 000 ids...the same query runs really fast with a couple of thousand ids...

```
Select '300_new_files_2012-02-29.xml' as Filelist,
Sum(coalesce(temp_decmetadata.glare_none, 0)) as glare_none,
Sum(coalesce(temp_decmetadata.glare_sun, 0)) as glare_sun,
Sum(coalesce(temp_decmetadata.precipitation_clear, 0)) as precipitation_clear,
Sum(coalesce(temp_decmetadata.precipitation_heavyFog, 0)) as precipitation_heavyFog,
Sum(coalesce(temp_decmetadata.precipitation_mediumRain, 0)) as precipitation_mediumRain,
Sum(coalesce(temp_decmetadata.spray_clear, 0)) as spray_clear,
Sum(coalesce(temp_decmetadata.spray_heavySpray, 0)) as spray_heavySpray,
Sum(coalesce(temp_kafasccmobjectdata.laneAssignment_farRight, 0)) as laneAssignment_farRight,
Sum(coalesce(temp_kafasccmobjectdata.laneAssignment_leftAdjacent, 0)) as laneAssignment_leftAdjacent,
Sum(coalesce(temp_kafasccmobjectdata.type_motorbike, 0)) as type_motorbike,
Sum(coalesce(temp_kafasccmobjectdata.type_truck, 0)) as type_truck,
Sum(coalesce(temp_kafasccmobjectdata.type_van, 0)) as type_van,
Sum(coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.countryCode_SK, 0)) as countryCode_SK,
Sum(coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.countryCode_SM, 0)) as countryCode_SM,
Sum(coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.countryCode_TR, 0)) as countryCode_TR,
Sum(coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.countryCode_UA, 0)) as countryCode_UA,
Sum(coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.countryCode_US, 0)) as countryCode_US,
Sum(coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.countryCode_ZA, 0)) as countryCode_ZA,
Sum(coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.local_illumination_cast_shadows, 0)) as local_illumination_cast_shadows,
Sum(coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.local_illumination_oncoming, 0)) as local_illumination_oncoming,
Sum(coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.roadCharacteristics_flat, 0)) as roadCharacteristics_flat,
Sum(coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.roadCharacteristics_hilly, 0)) as roadCharacteristics_hilly,
Sum(coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.roadLocation_city, 0)) as roadLocation_city,
Sum(coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.roadLocation_cityResidential, 0)) as roadLocation_cityResidential,
Sum(coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.sky_overcast, 0)) as sky_overcast,
Sum(coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.sky_partlyCloudy, 0)) as sky_partlyCloudy,
Sum(coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.timeOfDay_day, 0)) as timeOfDay_day,
Sum(coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.timeOfDay_Sunny_daytime, 0)) as timeOfDay_Sunny_daytime
from files
left join 
(
 Select id,
 count(case when glare like '%none%' then 1 end) as glare_none,
 count(case when glare like '%sun%' then 1 end) as glare_sun,
 count(case when precipitation like '%clear%' then 1 end) as precipitation_clear,
 count(case when precipitation like '%heavyFog%' then 1 end) as precipitation_heavyFog,
 count(case when spray like '%clear%' then 1 end) as spray_clear,
 count(case when spray like '%heavySpray%' then 1 end) as spray_heavySpray,
 from decmetadata
 where id in (1264853,1264854,1264855,1264856,1264857,.....)
 group by id 
) temp_decmetadata on temp_decmetadata.id = files.id 
left join 
(
 Select id,
 count(case when laneAssignment like '%farRight%' then 1 end) as laneAssignment_farRight,
 count(case when laneAssignment like '%leftAdjacent%' then 1 end) as laneAssignment_leftAdjacent,
 count(case when type like '%car%' then 1 end) as type_car,
 count(case when type like '%motorbike%' then 1 end) as type_motorbike,
 count(case when type like '%truck%' then 1 end) as type_truck,
 count(case when type like '%van%' then 1 end) as type_van
 from kafasccmobjectdata
 where id in (1264853,1264854,1264855,1264856,1264857,.....)
 group by id 
) temp_kafasccmobjectdata on temp_kafasccmobjectdata.id = files.id 
left join 
(
 Select id,
 count(case when countryCode like '%SK%' then 1 end) as countryCode_SK,
 count(case when countryCode like '%SM%' then 1 end) as countryCode_SM,
 count(case when countryCode like '%TR%' then 1 end) as countryCode_TR,
 count(case when countryCode like '%UA%' then 1 end) as countryCode_UA,
 count(case when countryCode like '%US%' then 1 end) as countryCode_US,
 count(case when countryCode like '%ZA%' then 1 end) as countryCode_ZA,
 count(case when sky like '%lowSun%' then 1 end) as local_illumination_cast_shadows,
 count(case when comments like '%oncomingevent%' then 1 end) as local_illumination_oncoming,
 count(case when roadCharacteristics like '%flat%' then 1 end) as roadCharacteristics_flat,
 count(case when roadCharacteristics like '%hilly%' then 1 end) as roadCharacteristics_hilly,
 count(case when roadLocation like '%city%' then 1 end) as roadLocation_city,
 count(case when roadLocation like '%cityResidential%' then 1 end) as roadLocation_cityResidential,
 count(case when roadLocation like '%countryRural%' then 1 end) as roadLocation_countryRural,
 count(case when sky like '%overcast%' then 1 end) as sky_overcast,
 count(case when sky like '%partlyCloudy%' then 1 end) as sky_partlyCloudy,
 count(case when timeOfDay like '%day%' then 1 end) as timeOfDay_day,
 count(case when sky like '%clear%' and timeofday ='day' then 1 end) as timeOfDay_Sunny_daytime
 from visionmetadata
 where id in (1264853,1264854,1264855,1264856,1264857,....)
 group by id 
) temp_visionmetadata on temp_visionmetadata.id = files.id 
where files.id in (1264853,1264854,1264855,1264856,1264857,....)
```

The result of "Explain Select ..." is attached:
[image]

Any ideas/suggestions/corrections???

Any help will be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: If I execute any sub-query (left-join query) separately, it doesn't take more than a couple of seconds to generate results...but the above query as a whole is almost never ending executing...

Answer (score 2):

yipes...

first: how about creating a structure to hold all the id's you want instead of writing 50,000 numbers into your query 3 or more times.?

second: try to eliminate the leading % on your code checks. (and create good indexes on those columns)

third: and i almost never suggest this - but maybe pre-calculate the totals and store them denormalized.

Comment: How do you mean with creating the structures to hold ids?
And all these columns can contain text more than required, thats why I need to put %.
Didn't get your third point either.

Comment: i mean create a table to hold the ids, then insert the 500 ids in there, then link to that in the query instead of listing the ids in the query.

Comment: the initial % is going to kill any chance of using an index...  you should try your best to get the data in a form that can take advantage of indexing and not need the initial %

Comment: denormalize means create a new table or column(s) and store calculated values in there instead of counting and summing in the query.  not normally recommended, but will save you computation time here.